Exception when initializing CastingDevicePicker in Unity for UWP (Hololens 2)
I'm currently working on a Unity project that targets UWP, and I need to implement a feature to connect via Miracast. I'm trying to use the CastingDevicePicker from the Windows Runtime API, but I'm encountering an exception during initialization.
Context:
Unity Version: 2021.3.4f1
Target Platform: UWP
Capabilities Activated : InternetClient/Webcam and more
Issue:
When I try to initialize CastingDevicePicker, I get the following exception:

Exception initializing CastingDevicePicker: Exception of type
'System.Exception' was thrown. at
Windows.Media.Casting.CastingDevicePicker..ctor () [0x00000] in
<00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at
InitializeCastingDevicePicker () [0x00000] in
<00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at <ConnectToMiracast>b__11_0
() [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

Code:
Here's the relevant code snippet:
using UnityEngine;
using System;
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Media.Casting;
#endif

public class MiracastConnector : MonoBehaviour
{
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
    private CastingDevicePicker picker;
#endif

    void Start()
    {
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(() => InitializeCastingDevicePicker(), false);
#endif
    }

#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
    private void InitializeCastingDevicePicker()
    {
        try
        {
            picker = new CastingDevicePicker();
            picker.Filter.SupportsVideo = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Exception initializing CastingDevicePicker: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToMiracast()
    {
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(() => 
        {
            try
            {
                picker.Show(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), Placement.Default);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Exception showing CastingDevicePicker: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }, false);
    }
}

Question:
Why am I encountering this exception, and how can I properly initialize the CastingDevicePicker in Unity for UWP? Is there something specific that needs to be done to use Windows Runtime APIs in Unity?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
